# ReactJS fetch JSON API Data -- The correct way?

Tags: json, rest, reactjs, babeljs, es6-promise

I have been fighting with ES6 trying to come up with, what should be, a pretty straightforward operation. I want to call JSON API data for Bitcoin from one of the three following websites:

1. https://cryptowat.ch
2. https://coinmarketcap.com/
3. https://www.cryptocompare.com/

All three sites API endpoints go straight to the price I want and I think this may be the problem. There is no array of data, just the specific price. In my example using #3 above, the only object is "USD". That being said, I think I'm overthinking the process as getting into APIs with much more data and arrays of data -- I have accomplished using ReactJS.

Trying to reach a single endpoint that shows up as the "State" in the React DOM Inspector as "USD" and is pulling in the correct price, I cannot get the price to render on the page even though ReactJS is seeing it and capturing it.

My code:

```
var BitcoinApp = React.createClass({

 getInitialState: function() {
   return {
     "USD": []
   }
 },

 componentDidMount: function() {

  var th = this;
  this.serverRequest = 
    axios.get(this.props.source)
      .then(function(result) {    
        th.setState({
          USD: result.data.USD
        });
      })
  },

componentWillUnmount: function() {
  this.serverRequest.abort();
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <span>
      {this.state.USD.map(function(Data) {
        return (
          <div key={Data.USD} className="testbtc">
             <p>{Data.USD}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </span>
  )
 }
 });

 ReactDOM.render(<BitcoinApp source="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=BTC&tsyms=USD&e=Coinbase" />, document.querySelector("#btcPrice"));
```

I will mention that I have done a lot of research into this and have found a lot of answers -- all different! Everyone knows the ReactJS docs are severely outdated so finding the right path with ReactJS is difficult to say the least. Also, I'm using "axios" to "GET" the API data as I've read that "fetch" isn't globally supported yet? Is this still the case in 2017?

Using the above method, I can see this in the Inspector:

[image]

But when I go over to the "Console" portion of the inspector, I'm told that "this.state.USD.map is not a function".

I feel like I'm right on the cusp of solving this task, but I think I'm getting something wrong with the mapping of the promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that:

```
th.setState({
   USD: result.data.USD
});
```

is seting not iterable object. I mean that `this.state.USD.map is not a function` means that USD is not an array (and you can see this in console).

Try this to see what happens:

```
th.setState({
   USD: [result.data.USD]
});
```

However tho, you wrote:

> There is no array of data, just the specific price.

then I think the best solution is to change just the render method and initial state:

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <span>
          <div className="testbtc">
             <p>{this.state.USD}</p>
          </div>
    </span>
  )
 }


 getInitialState: function() {
   return {
     "USD": "",
   }
 },
```

Comment: thank you!!! Second option worked best for my use case. Thank you for the explanation -- made total sense.